# How install Terminal Server(RDP) in Windows server 2003 Small Business Server

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have IBM System X Server with Windows Server 2003 SBS operating system and 10 user CAL for remote desktop .but i cant see terminal server option in Add or remove Component. Is their Any option to upgrade Win Server 2003 SBS to Standerd? Or any option to install Terminal Server Forcefully in Win Server 2003 SBS.!! Help Me

Answer (score 0):

See this article: [Microsoft TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758069%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Try looking under Roles instead (in 2008 there are features and roles).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in a Microsoft way, because Domain controllers are accessible only to Admin Users for the RDP session.

But you could change the Domain GPO so that you allow USers to log into the Domain controller.

Comment: Can you give me the details to change the domain GPO, i have 10 user cal license and need 10 user access simultaneously for using a erp application

Comment: Hmm. Try to look in the GPO of the domain server you should find a policy that defined Log on through terminal services. I can't check this because we don't have any 2003 SBS servers anymore..